# How to convert objects in to array of Array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have tried like this but it's not like what i need

```
Object.keys(data).forEach(function (key) {
    console.log(data[key]);
    array = $.map(data[key], function(value, index) {
       return [value];
    }); 
});
```

output i found -

```
0:{1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 7, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0, 10: 0, 11: 0, 12: 0}
1:{1: 3, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0, 10: 0, 11: 0, 12: 0}
2:{1: 0, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0, 10: 0, 11: 0, 12: 0}
```

please help me to get the result below :

```
0:[1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 7, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0, 10: 0, 11: 0, 12: 0]
1:[1: 3, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0, 10: 0, 11: 0, 12: 0]
2:[1: 0, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0, 10: 0, 11: 0, 12: 0]
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: please add the input data and use [literal notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) for the output as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just missing array push function of javasciprt

```
var array = [], finarr = [];
Object.keys(data).forEach(function (key) {
    //console.log(data[key]);
    array = $.map(data[key], function(value, index) {
    return [value];
    });
    finarr.push(array); 
});
```

it will give the right result i hope